# How to set a unified seed for random number generators in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, scientific-computing

I'm writing code and using existing functions from MATLAB. What if these functions use random number generators. Is there a way I can fix the seed of these functions without having to change their code ? Is there a command in MATLAB that does this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally code would use Matlab's built-in random number generator. You can seed it with the following:

```
rng         = RandStream.getDefaultStream;
rng.reset(your_seed_value_here);
```

One could also create `RandStream` objects and use them (thereby avoiding the default stream), but this should work most of the time.