# How to set the same initial seed random numbers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I have a matlab code which has a bunch of random numbers such as: `unifrnd(0,1)`, `normrnd(mu,sigma)`, this sort of functions get repeated over and over again.

Is there any way I can fix the random numbers that are generated? Meaning, I run the code once I get some results, on the second run I get different results (as expected). However, I want to make some experiences and it would be really helpful if I could fix the initial seed so that all randomness would be the same on the two runs.

Thanks,
V

edit: Would something like this work: `rand('seed', 57)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html),

```
rng(seed);
```

sets the seed of the random number generator.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What should I put in the "seed" argument? 
Would my suggestion above also work?

Comment: Put the line before calling any `rand` function.  `rng(seed)` seeds the random number generator using the nonnegative integer seed so that `rand`, `randi`, and `randn` produce a predictable sequence of numbers.

Comment: Well, I have more than 100 unifrnd and normrnd functions. There must be a single line of code that makes matlab produce a predictable sequence of random numbers. Probably this is the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891443/how-to-set-a-unified-seed-for-random-number-generators-in-matlab?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the seed should be set once at the top of your program.

Comment: Ok. Just did a quick test and rng(seed) works while  rand('seed', 57) does not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually sorry, when adding the line rng(seed); I get the following error:

Error using rng (line 95)
The current random number generator is the legacy generator.  This is because you have
executed a command such as rand('state',0), which activates MATLAB's legacy random
number behavior.  You may not use RNG to reseed the legacy random number generator.

Use rng('default') to reinitialize the random number generator to its startup
configuration, or call RNG using a specific generator type, such as
rng(seed,'twister').

Error in scgm99v13 (line 6)
rng(1);

Comment: add `rng('default')` before `rng(seed);`